# Making bluetooth scanning interface with tkinter?

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, bluetooth, raspberry-pi4

I am using the Python bluetooth module with Tkinter to create an app where users can choose to connect to Bluetooth. Can anyone help me to make a bluetooth device scanning interface on raspberry pi with Tkinter? The scanning device is output as a list on the interface. And is it possible to add the connect and pair parted?

```py
import time
from time import sleep
import serial
import bluetooth
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as font 

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import  ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import scrolledtext

import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()

main_window = tk.Tk()

main_window.title('Scan for nearby Bluetooth devices')

#changes the size of the screens window
window_width = 900
window_height = 500

screen_width = main_window.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = main_window.winfo_screenheight()

center_x = int(screen_width/2 - window_width / 2)
center_y = int(screen_height/2 - window_height / 2)

main_window.geometry(f'{window_width}x{window_height}+{center_x}+{center_y}')


main_window.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
main_window.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)


text = tk.Text(main_window, height=30, width=30)
text.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.EW)

def get_time():
    return now.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

text.insert('1.0','The time of the scan: ' + str(get_time()) + '\n\n')

def button_clicked():
    
    text['state'] = 'normal'

    now = datetime.datetime.now()

    def get_time():
        return now.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

    print()

    text.delete('0.0', tk.END)
    
    print("Scanning")  
    nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices(lookup_names=True)
    print("Found {} devices.".format(len(nearby_devices)))

    for addr, name in nearby_devices:
        print("  {} - {}".format(addr, name))
    return 
      
    text.insert('1.0','The time of the scan: ' + str(get_time()) + '\n\n')

    text.insert('0.0', 'Amount of devices found: ' + str(len(out)) + '\n\n')

    text['state'] = 'disabled'

main_button = ttk.Button(
    main_window,
    text='Scan again',
    command=lambda: button_clicked()
)

main_button.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.EW)

exit_button = ttk.Button(
    main_window,
    text='Exit',
    command=lambda: main_window.quit()
)

exit_button.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=tk.EW)

text['state'] = 'disabled'

main_window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

I used this for Raspberry Pi 4B.

```
nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices()

for bdaddr in nearby_devices:
    if target_name == bluetooth.lookup_name( bdaddr ):
        target_address = bdaddr
        break

if target_address is not None:
    print "found target bluetooth device with address ", target_address
else:
    print "could not find target bluetooth device nearby"
```